# Is using the style tag inside another tag considered "inline style"?

Tags: html, tags, styles, inline

I'm creating a basic HTML and CSS course and was wondering whether the use of the  tag inside another tag is called inline style.

```
  <p style="font-family:Impact"> blah </p>
```

Thank you.

Comment: The paragraph element is a block-level element. It is not an in-line element.

Comment: Doug, this is a collegial forum.  I am now reminding you of same.

Comment: The question is asking about inline CSS, not the inline display type.

Comment: I make the distinction local style sheet vs. inline since inline is already used in a specific way to define a type of element.  A local style sheet applies to one element.  They should be used only for creating one-time exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. 
On the other hand, I wouldn't recommend teaching the "inline style" anymore. 
It is considered as bad coding. In stead, drop this style and stick to internal and external stylesheets.

Read [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp) for more info on the different kinds of stylesheets

Answer (score -1):

It is a "local style sheet" that applies to a single element on a page.  Note that the `<p>` tag is a block-level (vertical) element.  This tag is not an in-line element.  Here is an example of an inline style sheet usage

```
<p>This is <span style = "color:red">way important</span>.</p>
```